# Azure Linux Web App is periodically restarting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am running my Angular (.Net Core) app on an Azure Linux Web App. I have noticed that periodically there are some performance issues which causes a request to take a lot longer to process than usual. From my analysis the app is being recycled/torn down etc and so the call that is taking longer is doing a cold start of the app.

I understand that Linux App Services are using the default Docker container to run the app, and looking at the logs I can see that there are some `docker run` commands executing when I see the slow performance, so it is starting the container at that point.

Also in Application Insights, when I drill down into the slow request I can see calls for the service to retrieve the `openid well-known configuration` which should only happen on start up.

Any ideas how I can keep a Linux Web App as always running? Or how to keep a Docker container always running? I've enabled 'Always On' in the App Service configuration of the Portal but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a configuration to set your Web App Always On. By default, after a define idle time, the app service is stopped. And when a new request arrive, it start the service again.

This why you see the `docker run` command on the log and the first query in the log.

For more information, you can check the FAQ [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues#how-do-i-decrease-the-response-time-for-the-first-request-after-idle-time). This part explain it well:

> **How do I decrease the response time for the first request after idle time?**
>
> By default, web apps are unloaded if they are idle for a set period of time. This way, the system can conserve resources. The downside is that the response to the first request after the web app is unloaded is longer, to allow the web app to load and start serving responses. In Basic and Standard service plans, you can turn on the Always On setting to keep the app always loaded. This eliminates longer load times after the app is idle. To change the Always On setting:
>
> In the Azure portal, go to your web app.
>
> - Select **Configuration**
> - Select **General settings**.
> - For **Always On**, select **On**.

Comment: that might work for a Windows app service that's running under IIS, but I'm using Linux